# SharePoint warmup script implementation

Tags: powershell, iis, warm-up

I've implemented the SPWarmup script from Codeplex on development and production environment. This script (that can be found here https://spbestwarmup.codeplex.com/) is working well, when I run it manually. Using the powershell script with the -install parameter created a scheduled task on server level that should run this script every 15 minutes.

Apparently after created, this don't do a lot. In task scheduler I have the task that should run the powershell script every 5 minutes and in history it's executed, but the SharePoint keeps slow.

Another remark is that when I run the script manually, it opens IE and visits all sites I defined, but when it's in a task, I don't do anything at all. Is there something I've missed here, or is there a good alternative as warmup script? Because first visitors (after some time) of the SharePoint have long load times.

Answer (score 1):

If your site(s) remain slow, you might want to check out this article about Microsoft clr...

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sofocle/archive/2012/07/24/sharepoint-still-slow-to-open-first-page-could-be-a-problem-with-microsoft-clr.aspx

When you run the script as a scheduled task, it probably runs under different user credential, this is why you don't see anything. Do you see the iexplore.exe process being launched in the task manager?

are you sure the account running the scheduled task has the rights to visit the SharePoint Sites?

Answer (score 0):

Why you need to run it every 5 min or so...typically App Pool Recycle(usually after mind AM hours).

If you place the empty character in the File path then may be issue. check this one.

https://spbestwarmup.codeplex.com/discussions/468743

If you have an error code please share it.

Answer (score 0):

We usually run a Start Up script or so called Warm up script at a scheduled time at the beginning of the day. This refreshes the App pool and in turn the subsequent IIS requests come faster like normal. You should not be doing this activity every 5 min . Remember that if you warm up all your sites/pages you will put a big memory pressure on the servers and to benefit from it you need to up the RAM. The important thing is to hit a few sites so the JIT is done for the assemblies and controls, not that all pages have cached data. If you "warm up" to many pages the IIS/ASP.NET will eventually start to throw out old cached data from memory.